# How can i fix my output will be 2 decimal Numbers ex:(.11) or it should be (.00)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get the output "total_amounts" like,ex(255.545645 = 255.54) and (150 =150.00). This is my code

```
$('.topag').on('input', function(){
var parent = $(this).closest('.calt');
var totalAmt = parseFloat(parent.find('.totalpr').val());
var quantity = parseFloat($(this).val());

parent.find('.total_amount').text(totalAmt*quantity);
$('#total_amounts').val(totalAmt*quantity);
$('#total_amounts').val(total);
calcul_total_quatities();
```

How can i fix this issue.

Comment: You are talking about javascript, not java. Fix your tags please.

Comment: Why is `php` here?

Comment: try to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php and example is in the manual

Comment: you can use the javascript method toFixed(2);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var total = 23.64654465;
var total_dec = total.toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById("load").innerHTML = total_dec;
```

```html
<p id="load"></p>
```

You can use the `toFixed()` method. The details for this can be found at the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp). See code below for coding needed for your scenario

```
var totalqty = totalAmt*quantity;
var total = totalqty.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("total_amounts").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: tried earlier but i didnt get.can you edit my code using toFixed(2); thanks in advance

Comment: your full coding is not added..

Comment: @user9394401 see coding added above

Comment: its not working.the value didint change

Comment: <input  type="text" name="topag" onKeyUp="checks()" placeholder="1" class="topag total_txt" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="totalpr" class="totalpr" value="<?php echo $toprice ?>"  />    OUTPUT    <span class="total_amount"></span>

Comment: make a fiddle with the problem, there's still code missing

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/twince/7r3f7o97/ this is my fiddle in this my output notworking.but my local host its working

Comment: have a look at the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7r3f7o97/1/)

Comment: thanks its working.

Comment: ,can you please check my updated fiddle,  If i enabled/disabled the checkbox button, the added .oo removed from the amount.How can i add the .oo to the amount?  fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twince/7r3f7o97/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144445/discussion-between-user9394401-and-sphinx).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144459/discussion-between-twinxz-and-sphinx).